# Electrical Characteristic of a piezo buzzer

Tags: voltage, ratings, piezo-buzzer

I stumbled upon this [piezo buzzer](http://www.farnell.com/cad/356850.pdf) and I don't know how to interpret its specifications. What's the difference between

**Rated Voltage (Vp-p Square Wave): 5Vp-p**

and

**Operating Voltage: 1 to 20 Vp-p**

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rated voltage, 5V p-p, is the voltage at which parameters such as current and sound output are valid. The operating voltage gives the maximum and minimum supply voltages. Below 1V the sound output is probably too low to be useful, and above 20V the unit is liable to be damaged. The specification could be clearer.

Comment: Would the resonant frequency remain the same regardless of the operating voltage?

Comment: @m.Alin - Yes. Resonance frequency is mechanically determined.